# Play 2 framework java 8 - "method code too large error"

Tags: java, java-8, playframework-2.2

I am using play 2.2.6 framework with java 8, AngularJS 1.4.2. I am getting the error **java.lang.RuntimeException: Method code too large!** ,
My scala.html file has size less than 65kb (if it could be the restriction) and also, the controller has 452 lines of code which should not be the problem.

This problem disappears when I remove some of the ROUTES from **routes** file.
I also tried to set the build.bat file in order to increase the max size of **routes** file as **java -Xms1024M -Xmx2048M -Xss8M -XX:+CMSClassUnloadingEnabled -XX:MaxPermSize=2048M** but still when I add one or two more routes then it shows me the same error.
Please help to get some workaround.
[Click to see error page](https://i.stack.imgur.com/uIu3d.jpg)

Comment: If I remember right, the maximum method byte code length is 64K. What if you extract some code to methods?

Comment: My controller is just 26KB, Actually I figured out that non of my controllers have bigger methods or they exceed the limit of even 30kb. But whenever I add some new methods in any of the controller and add them into ROUTES , it gives me the same error. Possibly routes max size is not increasing with the build.bat and it is getting out of capacity.

Comment: Any resolution to this?